# Why does my update(select from when) statement refuse to recognize my table alias?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I was looking through the AskTom site and found what should be a very powerful tool for update statments but my statement refuses to accept the alias after the subquery.
Can someone please explain this for me and possibly show a solution?

```
Update (SELECT T.Date_,T.Name_ 
        FROM TableA T, TableB P
        WHERE P.Date_ = T.Date_
        AND   P.Name_ = T.Name_) SET P.ID = T.Name_
```

There may be other issues as to how to run this type of update and That would be a bonus. I am more interested at this point in trying to understand the alias problem. I have tried to sub in

```
TableB.ID = TableA.Name_
```

but no luck

Specifically the error is ORA-00904 invalid identifier.

As always thanks in advance.

The above issue has been answered for me but I do have some others as I try to understand it.

I now get ORA-01779 cannot modify a column which maps to a non-key preserved table.
I presume this is referring to the table I'm trying to update correct? As I could update from a view or any other proper source that may not have a pk or fk.

Can this type of update statement work with Oracle temp tables or can I expect problems?

Can I use this type of statement with a case statement to update multiple columns in TableA or will there be problems?

Thanks again.

Comment: What does it mean to "refuse to accept the alias"?  What error do you get?  Do both `TableA` and `TableB` have columns `Date_` and `Name_`?

Comment: I've added the specific error above and yes both tables have the correct cols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you perform an `UPDATE (query)` operation, the only columns you can use outside the parentheses are the names of columns returned by the query - in this case Date_ and Name_.  The table aliases you used in the query are not valid outside the parentheses either.

What you therefore need is:

```
Update (SELECT P.ID ,T.Name_ 
        FROM TableA T, TableB P
        WHERE P.Date_ = T.Date_
        AND   P.Name_ = T.Name_) SET ID = Name_
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I'm trying to understand how it knows to update ID in TableB? What occurs if TableA also had an ID Column?

Comment: In that case you would be forced to give them different aliases in the subquery - e.g. `(select t.id, p.id as P_ID...`